# Array of objects filter with multiple validations

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of User objects with status as property in it.

Now i want to filter the objects using status it can either

Status:
Waiting
InProgress
JustResearch
NotInterested
NotApplicable
Intertested
AlreadyBooked

one more property eligibility 
10 
20
30

```
let array = Array<User> // assuming this has array of user values

let filteredArray = array.filter { !$0.status.contains("Waiting") || !$0.status.contains("JustResearch") !$0.status.contains("AlreadyBooked") || !$0.eligibility.contains("20")}
```

I need something like above filteredArray should contain only user objects with InProgress, JustResearch,NotInterested and NotApplicable

I am getting an error while i am trying use filter as above how can apply filter with multiple conditions.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: what do you meant by one more property eligibility 10 20 30 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

i modified your condition (ie `!$0.status.contains("Waiting")` to `$0.status.contains("InProgress")`) because you need only user objects with InProgress, JustResearch,NotInterested and NotApplicable.

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { $0.status.contains("InProgress") || $0.status.contains("JustResearch") || $0.status.contains("NotInterested") || $0.status.contains("NotApplicable")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You lost `||` after

```
!$0.status.contains("JustResearch")
```

This code will work:

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { !$0.status.contains("Waiting") || !$0.status.contains("JustResearch") || !$0.status.contains("AlreadyBooked")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't want to check if `status` **contains** a string, you want to check if `status` **is equal** to a string.

A possible solution is to create an *whiteList* array. Then you can check if the array **contains** the status.

```
let array = Array<User> // assuming this has array of user values
let whiteList = ["InProgress", "JustResearch", "NotInterested", "NotApplicable"]
let filteredArray = array.filter { whiteList.contains($0.status) }
```